# Change backgroundImage button on hover Titanium

Tags: button, mobile, hover, titanium

Is it possible to change the backgroundImage of a button in Titanium when it is hovered?
I have the following code for my button:

```
var btnLogin = Titanium.UI.createButton({
        title : 'Log in',
        top : '260',
        height : '50',
        width : '270',
        backgroundImage : '../images/button.png'
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

URL's are absolute, with the `Resources` folder as root:

```
var btnLogin = Titanium.UI.createButton({
    title : 'Log in',
    top : '260',
    height : '50',
    width : '270',
    backgroundImage : '/images/button.png'
});
```

Furthermore, if you look at the documentation, it indeed is possible: http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest/Titanium.UI.Button-object

Answer (score 0):

Rene's comment is helpful, but not an answer to the question asked.

Rene gives no indication that a separate backgroundimage can be specified for just the situation when the mouse hovers over the button. That's because IMHO there isn't.

Titanium was developed with mobile, hence touchscreens, in mind. The mobileweb platform has always been something of an afterthought.

As far as I can tell, there is no way to do the "hover" thing that's so useful on dekstop. There is some adjustment to Android's trackball (some devices apparently have one), with a 'focus' event and a few properties like 'backgroundFocusedColor', but those do not respond to hover/mouseover situations on mobileweb.

I'd love to be proven wrong.

Comment: Samsung S4 supports hover. Although can't find any api in Titanium to use it. For android Native [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnHoverListener.html) will work i think.